# Express Typescript API Validating Body Parameters in Router using Middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Im using Router classes to manage all my Routes:

```
const router = express.Router();
/**
 * User Sign up Route at /api/auth/register
 */
router.post(
  "/register",
  checkBodyParameters(['username', 'email', 'password']),
  verifyRegister.ensurePasswordStrength,
  verifyRegister.checkUsernameAndEmail,
  AuthController.register
);
export = router;
```

I want to check the x-www-form-urlencoded body parameters. To see if either the key is not what it should be, or the value is empty.

I wrote a middleware function to check that:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

export default function checkBodyParameters(
  bodyParams: Array<string>,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next
) {
  let requestBodyParams: Array<string> = [];
  requestBodyParams.push(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password);
  requestBodyParams.forEach((requestBodyParam) => {
    if (bodyParams.includes(requestBodyParam)) {
      if (requestBodyParam !== "") {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: "Paremeter cant be empty",
          value: requestBodyParam,
        });
      }
    } else {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Paremeter not specified", value: requestBodyParam });
    }
  });
}
```

But it seems like it doesnt like me passing Arguments to the middleware function in

```
checkBodyParameters(['username', 'email', 'password'])
```

My Question is how do i create a middleware function which acceppts more values than req, res and next? And how to use this function correctly with the router instance.

Any Feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function instead of returning a function as a middleware.

Instead, use:

```
const checkBodyParameters = (
  bodyParams: Array<string>
) => (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next
) => {
  let requestBodyParams: Array<string> = [];
  requestBodyParams.push(req.body.username, req.body.email, req.body.password);
  requestBodyParams.forEach((requestBodyParam) => {
    if (bodyParams.includes(requestBodyParam)) {
      if (requestBodyParam !== "") {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: "Paremeter cant be empty",
          value: requestBodyParam,
        });
      }
    } else {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Paremeter not specified", value: requestBodyParam });
    }
  });
}

export default checkBodyParameters
```

Comment: I dont know if my tsconfig is badly configured. But it in line 1 i get an error at the equal sign position saying '(' expected.

Comment: @JulianOtto My fault, try again :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Im pretty new into java/typescript and i always have some problems trying to export my stuff :)

Comment: Functions returning functions are tricky at the beggining ;)